# not able to download file with size more than 63kb using UnityWebRequest

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, unitywebrequest

i am try to download asset bundle from an url but the request keep on cancelling after downloading 63kb. Can anyone explain to me why this may be happening?

My Code :

```
public IEnumerator DL()
{
    string downloadlink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGyrB4-MQfo-HVom9ENvV4dn312_wL4Q/view?usp=sharing";
    string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/electroplatingNN";
    //Download
    UnityWebRequest dlreq = new UnityWebRequest(downloadlink);
    dlreq.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerFile(filepath);
    dlreq.timeout = 15;

    UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation op = dlreq.SendWebRequest();

    while (!op.isDone)
    {
        //here you can see download progress
        Debug.Log(dlreq.downloadedBytes / 1000 + "KB");

        yield return null;
    }

    if (dlreq.isNetworkError || dlreq.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(dlreq.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("download success");
    }

    dlreq.Dispose();

    yield return null;

}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the download link will work. I have never tried a file download like that from a Google Drive, but I would not be surprised if what you are actually getting is part of the front-end HTML instead of a partial file. I would try hosting a file under a direct path, or even setting up simple localhost server which "hosts" it.

Comment: after that do you get any error? adding to @Bart 's comment: For testing you could just use it on a local file path. If I enter the URL in my browser it forwards me to a page where I could click on download ... it is not the download itself!

Comment: I thought you had to use the right api for downloading files off google drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments the issue is not in the `UnityWebrequest` but rather Google Drive doesn't simply download your file as you expect.

Instead the data you download is actually only the web page which would allow you to download it. If I simply open your file in a browser I get a page looking like this

[image]

where I now **could** download your file.

---

There are packages like [this](https://github.com/Elringus/UnityGoogleDrive) or [this](https://github.com/midworld/unity-googledrive) which implement the necessary stuff for actually download files from Google Drive API in Unity.